# Why is this code segfaulting? (Pointer arithmetic)

Tags: c, pointers, char, segmentation-fault

For some reason this code is segfaulting for a reason I can't find out.

```
char *read_line(FILE *fp)
{
    char *out;
    int counter = 0;
    char c = getc(fp);

    while (c != '\n' && c != EOF)
    {
        *(out + counter) = c;
        counter++;
        c = getc(fp);
    }

    if (c == EOF || feof(fp))
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    *(out + counter) = '\0';
    return out;
}
```

I have already tried running it in `gdb`, and that has told me that the segfault is at `*(out + counter) = c;`. I can't figure out what I am doing wrong, can anyone else?

Comment: seems char * out is not initialized?

Comment: What would I initialize it to? O.o

Comment: If you want to read data to somewhere you need to provide the memory to do so. As the code currently stands `out` is just apointer to nowhere. And writing to where it points to provokes undefined behaviour and a crash.

Comment: I understand how pointers work, but I don't see why this doesn't work. What confuses me is how this usually works, but sometimes it decides to segfault for no good reason.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're not assigning any value to `out`, so it's probably pointing to some invalid memory address.

What you probably want to do is find the length of the data first, then allocating the required amount of memory, and then read the actual data into the allocated memory:

```
char *out;
int counter = 0;
char c = getc(fp);
while (c != '\n' && c != EOF) {
    counter++;
    c = getc(fp);
}

out = malloc(counter+1);
fseek(fp,0,SEEK_SET);

counter = 0;
c = getc(fp);
while (c != '\n' && c != EOF) {
    *(out + counter) = c;
    counter++;
    c = getc(fp);
}
*(out + counter) = 0;
```

And don't forget to `free(out)` when you're done using it...

BTW, instead of the second `for` loop, you could simply use `fgets(out,count,fp)`.

Comment: But what value WOULD I assign to it?

Comment: The address of an allocated piece of memory; see updated answer...

Comment: @alk You could try that as well, but no guarantees :)

Comment: `*(out + counter) = c;` - please don't. Readability is golden.

Comment: @H2CO3 I can read that just fine.

Comment: @AppleDash doesn't mean you should do it like this. perhaps be respectful to others to read your code? that pointer arithmetic plus dereferencing thingy is unidiomatic, at best.

Comment: @H2CO3, I agree, but I did not want to confuse OP any further, so copy-pasted from OP's question...

Comment: @H2CO3 This code is mostly for a "troll" fork of a project anyways, so perhaps less readable code is better. I'm only using C because that's what the original project uses.